# Using Powershell to monitor a log file in real time and send message if string does NOT show every x minutes

Tags: powershell, monitoring

Trying to figure out how to alert if string is NOT found every 5 minutes (alerts to process down).  To further complicate, the log file name remains the same, but new file is created once original file reaches 10 MB.

I am not the PowerShell guru.  I did find the following that alerts for string found:

```
Get-Content D:\temp\wow.log -Wait -Last 0 |
 Where-Object { $_ -match 'TROUBLE CONNECTING!!' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Send an email here, e.g.:
    # Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer exchange.example.com -From alerts@example.com -To jdoe@example.com -Subject 'Connection error' -Body $_
  }
```

Comment: Use two statements 1) $results = Get-Content D:\temp\wow.log -Wait -Last 0 |
 Where-Object { $_ -match 'TROUBLE CONNECTING!!' } 2) Then create a Foreach loop with a timer to alert when string is not found.

Comment: So what happens with the log file once it reaches its size limit? If you want a script to check every X minutes, use a scheduled task

Comment: So i believe i need to use the -notmatch operator.  Scheduling task may work.  At 10 MB, original file name increments with numeral and original file name starts over clean at 0 MB.  Will keep you posted...are we having fun yet?

Comment: Ok not yet.  Back to the drawing board